# Interested in learning about something new in SAS

Tags: sas

I am trying to create a decision tree in SAS. Whenever I run my SAS code I get an error message.

Could I have someone assistance?

```
Sample code:



   proc hpsplit data=credit;
           class default student;
           model default = student balance income
           output out=hpsliout;
           prune costcomplexity;
        run;
```

Comment: I am running SAS student edition.

Comment: What is the error and can you provide sample data ?

Comment: Hi Richard, I am getting a  ERROR: Procedure HPSPLIT not found.

Comment: I provided you with the answer in the same question you posted earlier.  The university/student edition does not have proc hpsplit.  It is written on this page: https://support.sas.com/software/products/university-edition/faq/limitations.htm